# Android seekbar style

Tags: android, seekbar, android-styles

I'm trying to create a custom seekbar for my Android application. I found many solutions but all of them are using "custom" drawing code for background. My seekbar is simple - i have an image (only one) for the background, and an image for the thumb. The problem i have is scaling: i want both "thumb" and "background" image to scale according to the size of the seekbar control. How to do that?
It's a bit funny that, when using images (drawables) as background / thumb Android won't scale them by default but leaves them in original size :)

Comment: That's why you use the 9.png to make custom seekbars.

Comment: Any example? May i use only one image for nine-patch?

Answer (score 6):

You can make the foreground, background and the slider of the thumb.

This is an alright tutorial:

[Tutorial 2](http://developer-dot-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/custom-seekbar-tutorial.html)

And here is how you make custom 9.png images:

[nine-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Comment: The first link is dead. This is a nice example of why answer should not be just collections of links but actually contain the answer

Answer (score 2):

1 You can use an xml (*progress.xml*) to define the look and feel of ProgressBar & place it inside the res directory.

2 The thumb can be defined inside the layout where the ProgressBar is declared.

3 The thumb can be an image (*imgthumb.png*) yet, I have noticed **2 best practices**

1. The best thumb height is **2.5 times** the **height** of the **ProgressBar**.
2. It is **best rendered** when the **height & width of the thumb image** are exactly the same as the **diameter of the thumb** (i.e. **for circular thumb**) & finally, **place different sizes** of the thumb in **each bucket** for different **pixel densities**.

Here are the sources

1 progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />

        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="#cccccc"
            android:startColor="#d3d3d3" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="0dp" />

            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="#ff0000"
                android:startColor="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />

            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="#1dc0ff"
                android:startColor="#1dc0ff" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

2 Defining the Seekbar in the layout with a custom thumb

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/song_seekbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".84"

        android:minHeight="8dip"
        android:maxHeight="8dip"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar"
        android:thumb="@drawable/imgthumb" />
```

Hope this helps you!